# Buggy HTTP header behavior with the `site` parameter. Improper caching?

Tags: bug, sites, caching

In [`sx.el`](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) we are using `url-request-extra-headers` to pass API requests to Stack Exchange.

When performing multiple queries in quick succession, we end up receiving the same JSON response even when the headers are different.  Specifically, the `site` parameter does not seem to be respected.  `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me/favorites` is the biggest culprit when trying to retrieve a list of all favorites across all sites (for caching).

We had switched from appending all the header arguments to the end of the URL `?site=site&filter=filter...` to passing them through headers to have a consistent interface for both `POST` and `GET` queries.

If we change the query to use `?site=site` but still pass the remainder of the arguments through headers the data is updated as expected.  Alternately we can wait ~1 minute between queries to ensure the data is updated.

Is this a limitation of passing arguments as headers with `GET`, or are we missing a parameter that would ensure that the change in `site` key is respected?